# EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'addInstrumentToStage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an `angular2` app with `typescript`, and i am using [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula).
Here is the constructor:

```
constructor(  private dragulaService: DragulaService,
              private audioFinderService:AudioFinderService) {}
```

and then ngOnInit():

```
public ngOnInit(): any {

        this.dragulaService.setOptions('second-bag', {

                  moves: function (el, container, handle) {

                              var file=this.audioFinderService.audioGetter();
                              this.audioFinderService.removeFromStage();
```

and in the line `this.audioFinderService.audioGetter();` it complains that:

```
error_handler.js:50 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'audioGetter' of undefined
```

i tried to make a dependency injection in the constructor, but it seems that, it does not recognize the `audioFinderService`

Here is the `AudioFinderService`

```
@Injectable()
export class AudioFinderService {
       constructor(private playService:SelectedInstrumentsService,private http:Http) { }
  }
```

The only wierd thing about AudioFinderService is that, it is injecting another service. So, **do you think, nested dependency injection is failed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 moves: function (el, container, handle) {//<-- 'this' will refer to the function object

                              var file=this.audioFinderService.audioGetter();
                              this.audioFinderService.removeFromStage();
```

to

```
 moves: (el, container, handle)=> {//<-- 'this' will refer to the page

                              var file=this.audioFinderService.audioGetter();
                              this.audioFinderService.removeFromStage();
```

The problem is when you are using `function` instead of fat arrow synthax, you are losing the `this` that is refering to the page.

I suggest you to take a look at this great answer on how to refer to the correct `this`: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485)